# natbib: comma-separated for \citenum and colon-separated for \citep

Tags: natbib

My little example is as follows:

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage[round]{natbib}
    \newcommand{\citea}[1]{[\citenum{#1}]}
    %\setcitestyle{comma}

    \begin{document}

    Please ref \citep{efron1996bootstrap,tibshirani1996regression}
    or ref \citea{efron2004least,hastie2015statistical}

    \bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
    %\nocite{*}
    \bibliography{test}

    \end{document}
```

where the `test.bib` contains

```
    @article{tibshirani1996regression,
        title={Regression shrinkage and selection via the lasso},
        author={Tibshirani, Robert},
        journal={Journal of the Royal Statistical Society: Series B (Methodological)},
        volume={58},
        number={1},
        pages={267--288},
        year={1996},
        publisher={Wiley Online Library}
    }

    @article{efron1996bootstrap,
        title={Bootstrap confidence levels for phylogenetic trees},
        author={Efron, Bradley and Halloran, Elizabeth and Holmes, Susan},
        journal={Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences},
        volume={93},
        number={23},
        pages={13429--13429},
        year={1996},
        publisher={National Acad Sciences}
    }

    @article{efron2004least,
        title={Least angle regression},
        author={Efron, Bradley and Hastie, Trevor and Johnstone, Iain and Tibshirani, Robert},
        journal={The Annals of Statistics},
        volume={32},
        number={2},
        pages={407--499},
        year={2004},
        publisher={Institute of Mathematical Statistics}
    }

    @book{hastie2015statistical,
        title={Statistical learning with sparsity: the lasso and generalizations},
        author={Hastie, Trevor and Tibshirani, Robert and Wainwright, Martin},
        year={2015},
        address={Boca Raton},
        publisher={CRC press}
    }
```

I know that `\setcitestyle{comma}` can change the punctuation. 
However, I want keep the colon-separated way for `\citep` by default, 
and use the comma-separated way for `\citea` which is modified from `\citenum`.

Comment: Is something stopping you from writing `[\citenum{efron2004least},\citenum{hastie2015statistical}]`?

Comment: Incidentally, with your setup, the formatted bib entries will *not* be associated with numbers such as `[1]`, `[2]`, etc. Hence, your readers may find that citation call-outs of the form `[3,4]` are not all that helpful. (In fact, readers may find it to be the very opposite of helpful…)

Comment: You're quite right! Tks! @Mico